# Firebase In-App message crashing after enabled Proguard in release mode

Tags: android

java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError at c.b.a.a.f.b.a(Unknown Source:0) at c.b.a.a.e.c.nc.(Unknown Source:12) at c.b.a.a.b.a.(Unknown Source:8) at com.google.firebase.inappmessaging.internal.injection.modules.ClearcutLoggerClientModule.providesClearcutClient(Unknown Source:5) at enter code herecom.google.firebase.inappmessaging.internal.injection.modules.ClearcutLoggerClientModule_ProvidesClearcutClientFactory.get(Unknown Source:10) at com.google.firebase.inappmessaging.internal.injection.modules.ClearcutLoggerClientModule_ProvidesClearcutClientFactory.get(Unknown Source:0) at d.a.b.get(Unknown Source:15) at com.google.firebase.inappmessaging.internal.injection.modules.ClearcutLoggerClientModule_ProvidesApiClientFactory.get(Unknown Source:4) at com.google.firebase.inappmessaging.internal.injection.modules.ClearcutLoggerClientModule_ProvidesApiClientFactory.get(Unknown Source:0) at d.a.b.get(Unknown Source:15) at com.google.firebase.inappmessaging.internal.DisplayCallbacksFactory_Factory.get(Unknown Source:58) at com.google.firebase.inappmessaging.internal.DisplayCallbacksFactory_Factory.get(Unknown Source:0) at com.google.firebase.inappmessaging.FirebaseInAppMessaging_Factory.get(Unknown Source:20) at com.google.firebase.inappmessaging.FirebaseInAppMessaging_Factory.get(Unknown Source:0) at d.a.b.get(Unknown Source:15) at com.google.firebase.inappmessaging.internal.injection.components.DaggerAppComponent.providesFirebaseInAppMessaging(Unknown Source:2) at com.google.firebase.inappmessaging.FirebaseInAppMessagingRegistrar.providesFirebaseInAppMessaging(Unknown Source:116) at com.google.firebase.inappmessaging.FirebaseInAppMessagingRegistrar.lambda$getComponents$0(Unknown Source:0) at com.google.firebase.inappmessaging.FirebaseInAppMessagingRegistrar$$Lambda$1.create(Unknown Source:2) at com.google.firebase.components.Lazy.lambda$new$0(Unknown Source:0) at com.google.firebase.components.Lazy$$Lambda$1.get(Unknown Source:4) at com.google.firebase.components.Lazy.get(Unknown Source:15) at com.google.firebase.components.AbstractComponentContainer.get(Unknown Source:8) at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime.get(Unknown Source:0) at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime.initializeEagerComponents(Unknown Source:46) at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeAllApis(Unknown Source:20) at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source:73) at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source:2) at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source:35) at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source:4) at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1917) at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1892) at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source:3) at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6239) at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5805) at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5722) at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0) at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1656) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807) Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: throw with null exception at c.b.a.a.f.b.(Unknown Source:3)

Answer (score 0):

You might have to ignore the classes used by firebase response in proguard rules so that they can be mapped to gson successfully.